# FlowDocument class .NET class

Tags: c#

what is the compatible class of `FlowDocument` in c# to c++ language. And please get me a link for its corresponding documentation.

Comment: Seems like a very vague question to me, the FlowDocument class really is based upon a requirement from the .net community and framework, I don

Answer (score 1):

Strange question: any .NET framework class (WPF subsection in this case) is available in all .NET languages. Unless you're talking about other C++ implementations (like Borland) and not C++.NET, but then you obviously don't have WPF at all...

I guess you don't find it right away because you're missing a reference to PresentationFramework.dll in your C++ project.

FlowDocument class is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx

Comment: My requirement is platform independent and i am writing under gnu C++ compiler  .I have to create an object having properties of FlowDocument class. Is there no solution for it then.

Answer (score 0):

The [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx) class may be accessed from any .NET language.